# Word Interop Not Extracting Data

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, com-interop

I'm using Word 2016 and I'm having trouble getting data from the object.

My snippet is as such:

```
    void Application_DocumentOpen(Word.Document document)
    {
        var test = document.Paragraphs;
    }
```

Before the assignment looking at paragraphs gives:

Evaluation of method Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.get_Paragraphs() calls requires a COM call. Evaluation of methods on COM objects is not supported in this context.

After it simply gives: System._ComObject with the member NativeView  which has 0x0df4fd18

I've tried searching both errors, but haven't found related results.

**UPDATE**
So I compared this to the example they give, which is:

```
    void Application_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
        Doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text = "This text was added by using code.";
    }
```

What's neat is that if I look at `Doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text` for their example, I get the text of the paragraph. If I try to do it with my version I get: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Paragraphs'

So... Paragraphs isn't returning what I expect it to. Is it possible that I don't have access to the document since the method is firing before it loads?

Comment: Your first error is a limitation of the debugger. Can you explain what you want to do? Be able to see the text contain within the paragraphs?

Comment: My long term goal is to section the document by numbered lists, but I'm just trying to get access to the data at this point. Are you suggesting that the debugger can't see the data even though it's been acquired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently only the methods/properties that have been called exist within the class. It makes sense, since it prevents the object from loading massive amounts of data constantly, but it was a bit confusing to debug.

In any case, changing test to doc.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text seems to have made the object viewable.